# Extract a substring in R

Tags: r, substring, gsub

```
> ldata2[2]
    [1] "  \"pretty\": \"5:06 PM GMT on June 18, 2015\","
# Need to extract only the time information. In this case "5:06 PM GMT on June 18, 2015"
# My attempt
> time <- sub(".* :\"(.*)".*","\\1",ldata2[1])
```

This is the error message i get : `Error: unexpected symbol in "time <- sub(".* :\"(.*)"."`
Help appreciated

Comment: You forgot to escape your second quotation mark.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde I don't quite see it. Could you point it out?

Comment: How many quotation marks are in your pattern?

Comment: @MatthewPlourde 6 in total from the beginning of the string.

Comment: The pattern is the first argument to `sub`. It contains two quotation marks, and you forgot to escape the second one: ".* :\"(.*)\".*"

Comment: Remember that what you see in the terminal isn't exactly what R sees. use `cat` for reference

Comment: @MatthewPlourde I tried your solution. Spits back the exact same string. No sub is done. Any ideas?

Comment: There is no space between "pretty" and the colon. The space is after the colon.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde Ah yes. Oversight. Thanks a lot. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern does not match the string so nothing is replaced. Here is the correct pattern:

```
sub(".*: \"(.*)\".*","\\1",ldata[2])
```

Comment: Quite right. I also missed the \ after (.*). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
library(stringr)
str_match(x, ': \\"(.*)\\"')[2]
#[1] "5:06 PM GMT on June 18, 2015"
```

`cat` was used as reference in creating the regex pattern.

```
x <- "  \"pretty\": \"5:06 PM GMT on June 18, 2015\","
cat(x)
"pretty": "5:06 PM GMT on June 18, 2015",
```

The backslashes are gone. I don't even reference them in my regex. The pattern `': \\"(.*)\\"'` starts with the colon, a space and one set of double quotes. The colon and space do not need special characters. The double quotes have special regex meaning so the set is escaped with two backslashes. Next the capture group and another escaped double quote set.

With sub:

```
sub('.*: \\"(.*)\\",', '\\1', x)
[1] "5:06 PM GMT on June 18, 2015"
```

Comment: Or  `gsub('.*:\\s*"|",$',"",x)`